# Does the brahman have the prakrutik body just like human beings have?

Tags: philosophy, brahman, body

Does the brahman has ears, eyes, legs and hands? If so, what are the sources which specify about the body structure for brahman? What do Dvaita, Advaita and Vishishadvaita say about it?

Comment: Are you asking about brahman or devta? Brahmans are just like any other human beings with their ancestors having sort of actual relationship with the gods or their incarnations .

Comment: the brahman of Vaishnavite sects is a person (vishnu,krishna,rama)- although their body is not of the material world - they wear dresses,ornaments etc and carry weapons.

Answer (score 2):

Brahman has no body. Shruti is very explicit about it. Following is from Ishavasya Upanishad.

> स पर्यगाच्छुक्रमकायमव्रणमस्नाविरँ् शुद्धमपापविद्धम् ।
>
> कविर्मनीषी परिभूः स्वयंभूर्याथातथ्यतोऽर्थान्व्यदधाच्छाश्वतीभ्यः समाभ्यः ।। 1.1.8 ।।
>
> ।।1.1.8।।. He (Atman) is all-pervading, bright, **bodiless, scatheless, without muscles**, pure, untouched by sin (evil), wise (seer), omniscient, transcendent, self-sprung. He duly alloted to the various eternal creators their respective functions.

**Objection**: then how do we consider the Avataras? Krisha / Rama , being having the prakrutik body

**Answer**: Whenever there is loss of Dharma, Ishwar takes form which is called Avatar. Ram, Krishna etc they are the same Bramhan in different forms. So is Bramha, Vishnu and Shiva. Like there's no difference between air and wind. There's no difference between Bramhan without and with body. In the second case, that is Bramhan with body, the Bramhan who by nature is stationary / immutable / without body appears to take the moving form because Bramhan is all powerful and can do anything. Even though it may appear as if Bramhan has taken a body, it still remains without a body. Like motion doesn't change nature of air which is stationary, although people may call it by the name of wind. Similarly moving Bramhan (one with sankalpa / saguna) is exactly the same as stationary one that is without a body. Temporarily He may seem to appear with a body because of the upaadhi It has taken onto itself. Why? Because it is all powerful.

> अव्यक्तं व्यक्ितमापन्नं मन्यन्ते मामबुद्धयः।
>   परं भावमजानन्तो ममाव्ययमनुत्तमम्।। BG 7.24।।
>
> The foolish think of Me, the Unmanifest, as having manifestation (human form), knowing not My higher, immutable and most excellent nature.

Comment: then how do we consider the Avataras? Krisha / Rama , being having the prakrutik body.

Comment: @Arun I've updated the answer answering your doubt.

Answer (score 2):

The param brahman is bodyless as defined in Vedas.

- Yajurveda 40:8

> 8. He hath attained unto the Bright, **Bodiless**, Woundless, Sinewless, the Pure which evil hath not pierced. Far-sighted, wise, encompassing, he self-existent hath prescribed aims, as propriety demands, unto the everlasting Years